# SQL Condition in a Conition

Tags: conditional-statements

im sorry that i cant google that questions, its mainly because i dont know the words for searching it up.

Im still new to sql and i have to solve a problem - Lets say my table looks like this:

```
ID       DATUM       NAME
1114     20200101    Heins
1114     20190101    Heins
1114     20200101    Norma
1115     20200102    Dirk
1111     20200102    Alex
```

I want to see every entry with the ID 1114 and the Date between 20200101 and 20200131.
So my statement looks like this:

```
SELECT
        *
FROM
        stackoverflowtable
        
WHERE 
DATUM BETWEEN '20200101' AND '202200131'
    AND ID = '1114' 
    OR ID = '1115'
```

This shows the correct date BUT ALSO every other date because of "AND ID 1114"

So i need a way to say search IN THE RANGE OF THE DATE FOR ID.

im sure its simple but i cant google it because lack of knowledge for the right words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way the where clause is processed you are getting results that are between 20200101 and 202200131 and also have an id of 1114 and results where the id is 1115.

Adding some bracketing to your where clause should force it to process the or around only the id fields and make the date a requirement for either.

```
SELECT
        *
FROM
        stackoverflowtable
        
WHERE 
DATUM BETWEEN '20200101' AND '202200131'
    AND (ID = '1114' 
    OR ID = '1115')
```

Comment: @EGOiST please give credit by marking the answer...

Comment: Oh! im Sorry. I am new to stackoverflow. Its now marked! Thanks for pointing it out